# Fastest way to download from web

Tags: c#, download

I would like your opinions on what the best/fastest way to download files from a webserver would be?

I have used WebClient. but most of the time it downloads slower than my web broswer...

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
using(c)
{
     c.DownloadFile("http://blahblah.com/somefile.html", "righthere.html");
}
```

Comment: post the code your have. Then we can see if its your code making it go slow

Comment: thank you - please see updated question for code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPWebResponse + StreamReader Very Slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901323/httpwebresponse-streamreader-very-slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the sample code for HttpWebRequest() from msdn doc?  I've used it literally billions of times with fantastic results.  Define  slower--  Twice as long?  Are you counting your browser start time in your comparison?

Comment: Thanks for the mention... Yeah, I have been counting... Very impatiently. It took 1 second for Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7 to display Google.com (after i deleted all internet history etc). And it took more than 15 seconds for WebClient