# c# ReadToEnd slow performance with large xml files

Tags: c#, performance

I get huge xml file from a service, and Im facing some performance issue with readtoend which is taking about 2 minutes to complete with 3 replace() and 1.3 minutes without using replace().

```
 HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
result = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\t", "");   
         sr.Close();
        //ReadToEnd it is taking about 2 minutes to complete 
}
```

What to use to overcome this performance issue.

**Edited** 
The xml file size is 2.77 MB

Comment: Are you saying the 3 Replaces take 0.7 minutes? And is that the problem you want to solve?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901323/httpwebresponse-streamreader-very-slow looks like a good bet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to solve both issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use .Replace("\n", "") you actually copy entire string , in this case you doing it 3 times , a better approach would be to read this into String builder and making replace there, you can also reading and adding chars from string builder one char at a time and skipping the ones you don't need.

Comment: Regex will solve a problem of string duplication if you write it correctly but it can be slower in evaluating the string, try to measure it